# Outer variable usage in the thread

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, thread-safety

Is there any difference in usage of local variables which are declared out of the new thread?

```
string emailSubject = "New message notification";
string imagePath = somePath;
string conversationName = entity.Name;

new Thread(delegate()
{
    foreach (var user in participantList)
    {
        string newEmailBody = emailBody.Replace("###ImagePath###", imagePath)
                                           .Replace("###UserName###", user.Name)
                                           .Replace("###ConversationName###", conversationName);

        MailUtil.SendEmail(user.Email, emailSubject, newEmailBody);
     }
 }).Start();
```

Is it more safe to declare them in the new thread? Like this:

```
new Thread(delegate()
{
    string emailSubject = "New message notification";
    string imagePath = somePath;
    string conversationName = entity.Name;

    foreach (var user in participantList)
    {
        string newEmailBody = emailBody.Replace("###ImagePath###", imagePath)
                                           .Replace("###UserName###", user.Name)
                                           .Replace("###ConversationName###", conversationName);

        MailUtil.SendEmail(user.Email, emailSubject, newEmailBody);
    }
}).Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of three your variables in your example are immutable ([`string` is immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)) then there is no difference which implementation to choose. The only difference is that in first example your variable (pointer) could be changed from other thread in other cases it's safe. But when you use complex types you have to ensure that your types are [thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8544e2s.aspx) because in other way simultaneous operations on your variables in different thread could lead to corrupted state.

Comment: What about garbage collector? For the first variant would GC "know" that these variables still in use?

Comment: @Pal Yes. The GC is smart enough to track such a variables. In the first case so called `closure` procedure is applied. Generally you shouldn't warry about GC but knowing about the GC's algotithms could help you design your applications better.